# switch_root with systemd: "Too many levels of symbolic links"

Tags: arch-linux, boot, linux-kernel, systemd, initramfs

I'm trying to boot a proprietary kernel build and OS after an upgrade to libc and numerous other tools. I'm booting using an initramfs in the 3.2.0 kernel with some utilities, like busybox. However, because of updates to udev 172 and systemd 43, there are significant changes in how `systemd` seems to be structured. I used to boot using `init=/bin/systemd`, now that seems to be `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd`, however just changing the `init` value doesn't work as I get this error and kernel panic:

```
# exec /bin/busybox switch_root /mnt/rootfs /usr/lib/systemd/systemd ro rootwait
BusyBox v1.20.2 (2014-05-28 13:23:51 IST) multi-call binary.

Usage: switch_root [-c /dev/console] NEW_ROOT NEW_INIT [ARGS]

Unmounting /proc
Executing switch_root and spawning init
switch_root: can't execute '/usr/lib/systemd/systemd': Too many levels of symbolic links
[49290.074730] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
[49290.093029] Backtrace:
[49290.100574] Function entered at [<c0017160>] from [<c0410744>]
[49290.118584]  r6:4024473c r5:cf01bc00 r4:c0cdbb08 r3:60000013
[49290.136081] Function entered at [<c041072c>] from [<c04109c0>]
[49290.154074] Function entered at [<c0410950>] from [<c003e240>]
[49290.172069]  r3:c0cac4a4 r2:0000001c r1:00000001 r0:c0457748
[49290.189560]  r7:000000f8
[49290.197366] Function entered at [<c003dbdc>] from [<c003e348>]
[49290.215360]  r7:000000f8
[49290.223152] Function entered at [<c003e2f4>] from [<c003e3b8>]
[49290.241147]  r4:00000001 r3:00000001
[49290.252176] Function entered at [<c003e3a0>] from [<c0013a80>]
```

Does anyone have any ideas whether the symbolic links error is coming from busybox's switch_root or the starting `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd` process?

I'm assuming switch_root has issues interpreting something, but it's probably systemd that I don't have configured correctly.

I'm just coming up empty with ideas as to how to debug this.

Here's the `ls -ld` output (sorry about the messy comments below):

```
# ls -ld /mnt/rootfs/usr/lib/systemd/
drwxrwxr-x    7 0        0             4096 Jan  8 01:21 /mnt/rootfs/usr/lib/systemd/
#
# ls -ld /mnt/rootfs/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        0           674468 Apr 12  2016 /mnt/rootfs/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

Here's the `strace` output:

```
# exec strace -f /bin/busybox switch_root /mnt/rootfs /usr/lib/systemd/systemd r
o rootwait
execve("/bin/busybox", ["/bin/busybox", "switch_root", "/mnt/rootfs", "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd", "ro", "rootwait"], [/* 6 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1a45000
uname({sys="Linux", node="(none)", ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x400ac000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbe9d3540) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbe9d3540) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbe9d3540)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l", 0xbe9d3540)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbe9d3540) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon", 0xbe9d3540)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/vfp", 0xbe9d3540)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls", 0xbe9d3540)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbe9d3540) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon", 0xbe9d3540)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/vfp", 0xbe9d3540)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l", 0xbe9d3540)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon/vfp", 0xbe9d3540)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon", 0xbe9d3540)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/vfp", 0xbe9d3540)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\250g\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1242860, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1312160, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x400d3000
mprotect(0x401fe000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x4020e000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12b) = 0x4020e000
mmap2(0x40211000, 9632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40211000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40214000
set_tls(0x402144c0, 0x40214ba8, 0x4004b000, 0x402144c0, 0x4004b000) = 0
mprotect(0x4020e000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x4004a000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
chdir("/mnt/rootfs")                    = 0
stat64("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat64(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getpid()                                = 771
mmap2(NULL, 45056, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x402ba000
mmap2(NULL, 401408, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40307000
brk(0)                                  = 0x1a45000
brk(0x1a67000)                          = 0x1a67000
munmap(0x40307000, 401408)              = 0
munmap(0x402ba000, 45056)               = 0
write(2, "BusyBox v1.20.2 (2016-04-12 15:5"..., 41BusyBox v1.20.2 (2016-04-12 15:51:37 IST)) = 41
write(2, " multi-call binary.\n", 20 multi-call binary.
)   = 20
write(2, "\nUsage: ", 8
Usage: )                = 8
write(2, "switch_root", 11switch_root)             = 11
write(2, " ", 1 )                        = 1
write(2, "[-c /dev/console] NEW_ROOT NEW_I"..., 42[-c /dev/console] NEW_ROOT NEW_INIT [ARGS]) = 42
write(2, "\n\n", 2

)                     = 2
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
Unmounting /proc
Executing switch_root and spawning init
switch_root: can't execute '/usr/lib/systemd/systemd': Too many levels of symbolic links
[   52.064978] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
[   52.083278] Backtrace:
[   52.090828] Function entered at [<c0017160>] from [<c0410764>]
[   52.108828]  r6:40259730 r5:cf01bc00 r4:c09c1b08 r3:600b0013
[   52.126328] Function entered at [<c041074c>] from [<c04109e0>]
[   52.144324] Function entered at [<c0410970>] from [<c003e240>]
[   52.162319]  r3:c09924a4 r2:00000020 r1:00000001 r0:c0457750
[   52.179817]  r7:000000f8
[   52.187621] Function entered at [<c003dbdc>] from [<c003e348>]
[   52.205616]  r7:000000f8
[   52.213410] Function entered at [<c003e2f4>] from [<c003e3b8>]
[   52.231416]  r4:000a0138 r3:ffffffff
[   52.242451] Function entered at [<c003e3a0>] from [<c0013a80>]
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any useful information in that. Looking at the busybox code, it does a `chroot`, cleans up the old mounted dir and runs an `execv` with my `init` command.

Comment: In that busybox shell before the `switch_root`, can you show `ls -ld` for each element of the `/mnt/rootfs/usr/lib/systemd/systemd` path (don't use trailing slashes)? If there is a symlink you should investigate where it points to and why it might fail...

Comment: I may have been using the wrong path, but I think that `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd` is the systemd executable rather than a path:

<code>
    # ls -ld /mnt/rootfs/usr/lib/systemd/
    drwxrwxr-x    7 0        0             4096 Jan  8 01:21 /mnt/rootfs/usr/lib/systemd/
    #
    # ls -ld /mnt/rootfs/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
    -rwxr-xr-x    1 0        0           674468 Apr 12  2016 /mnt/rootfs/usr/lib/systemd/systemd</code>

Comment: If you're running out of ideas to narrow down where the error comes from, maybe that's because you need to learn the magic that is `strace -f`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added strace to the initramfs, output posted above. Trying to get my head around busybox's switch_root and where/how it runs the init command.   
I've actually tried running `switch_root /mnt/rootfs /bin/bash` out of curiosity (would assume it should be possible to just boot into a shell) and it oddly enough still attempts to run /usr/lib/systemd/systemd as above, as if nothing... :-/